# What are the Edition requirements for APEX Rest API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, editions

The [Apex REST API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/asynch_api_rest.htm?CSHID=asynch_api_rest.htm) states that `Apex REST is currently available through a pilot program. For information on enabling Apex REST for your organization, contact salesforce.com.`

However, I can't find this wording or reference to this "pilot program" anywhere else,  or dates on any of this information, including a [technical library post on using the Apex REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST).

Is the API still in `pilot` mode? If not, what Editions of Salesforce is the API enabled for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be accessible in any org where the SOAP API is enabled. For professional edition orgs this would mean either [buying the API add-on pack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/19064/60) or being part of a [managed application with a special ClientId token](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm) that allows it to invoke the API.

If you have a PE org with the API add-on I'd contact support since I believe it's possible for  the REST API to be disabled per-org and there might be some historical reason it's not enabled that support can fix via black tab.

Comment: Do you have any links that reference or talk about the `API add-on pack`, or that talk about the `special identifier` for managed applications?

Comment: @John I added links, but wasn't able to find any official salesforce docs about the API addon for PE. I linked to an sfdcfox answer which was the best I could find on the open web to support it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a post on the Salesforce developer forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009A9fIAE) dated September 2011:

> The Apex REST API was available as a pilot in Summer '11 and continues
>   to be in pilot in this Winter '12 release. You can use Apex REST to
>   implement custom Web services in Apex and expose them through the REST
>   architecture.

Looks like it's available for all editions Professional and up - as @Matthew Mitchener stated, you have to have at least Professional in order to access APEX development.

> In a week or two we'll turn the feature on for everybody.

[The developers guide I linked to](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/Template/Splash.htm) my question is dated as last updated July 22, 2011. Looks like the REST Web Service is explained more fully (and updated) inside the [APEX API docs.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_rest.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a custom API endpoint you need at least Entreprise edition. This is because you need access to custom Apex development. Not sure if it's a pilot program, I've honestly never tried building one.

If you are simply trying to access Salesforce data from an external source, I don't think it matters what edition you have. Here's a guide for creating REST API requests: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/