# Professional Edition + Web Services API for a third-party website

Tags: webservices, professional-edition

I'm working on a third-party application that pushes and pulls data to/from Salesforce using Salesforce's REST API. We use this data to provide a visual workspace for sales reps that automatically stays in sync with Salesforce.

We just had a potential customer reach out who is on the Professional Edition. If our customer purchases the Web Services API, will that be enough to enable my application to communicate with Salesforce through the REST API?

Here's some more context in case it's helpful:

- Our application is not on AppExchange and is not hosted within Salesforce. Customers will log into our website and then connect their Salesforce instance through our site.
- Our app works with Salesforce's Enterprise Edition. We've never tested it on the Professional Edition with the Web Services add-on (is there even a way to do this as a developer without purchasing actual licenses?)
- Some forums make it sound like the third-party app must be [hosted through AppExchange](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-Professional-Edition-of-salesforce-have-API-capabilities) or be [whitelisted by Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm) to leverage the Web Services API add-on in the Professional Edition. Others like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19045/what-features-do-we-get-by-enabling-web-services-api-in-professional-edition) make it sound like it'll work for our use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It will be enough to communicate with Salesforce through standard, out of the box Salesforce REST APIs. As a partner, you can [create an org](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Orgs) similar/identical to your customer's org (without the data) and test your integration there. Your app does not need to be on AppExchange to integrate with your customer's Salesforce org.

Comment: Following up, the customer purchased the Web Services API add-on and our application is now able to communicate with Salesforce through the REST API. identigral's answer is correct and verified.